# In Bell's inequality, why is the expected correlation given by $C_q(\mathbf a,\mathbf b)=-\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

In its [article about Bell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem), wikipedia states [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem#Bell_inequalities) that the value of the correlation:

$$ C_q(a, b) = \left\langle A \left|(\boldsymbol\sigma \cdot \mathbf b)^{(2)}(\boldsymbol\sigma \cdot \mathbf a)^{(1)}\right| A \right\rangle $$

is

$$ C_q(a, b) = -\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b $$

without any reference nor explanation.

I'm interested in understand these expressions and how to pass from first to second one. Please, could someone provide an explanation or proof, or a reference to a free text where this explanation could be found.

At least, a key term that I can use to Google for it :-). No success with "antisimetric spin particles correlation" nor similars.